# Sharepoint App Fabric Installation in Startup Loop

Tags: sharepoint

I'm attempting to install Sharepoint 2016 on Windows Server 2016 and I'm having issues with the prerequisite installer, namely App Fabric.
The prerequisiteinstaller doesn't want to connect to the internet to download the file, throwing out:

```
Error: InternetOpenUrl failed (0X80072F07=-2147012857)
```

According to forums, this is due to a box being checked for *warn about changing between secure and not secure mode* but it was already unchecked. 
Next, I decided to manually install the thing using cmd and again, the prerequisiteinstaller, so I placed the exe in the root of C: drive and ran this command:

```
prerequisiteinstaller.exe /appfabric:c:\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe
```

And it seemed like we were away. However, upon extracting the files, it asks for a reboot, which I do, and then proceeds to restart the entire operation, again asking for a reboot at the end. This process will continue indefinitely as I've found out. The error logs show the following (or a portion thereof):

```
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Operating System: Windows 10
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Processor architecture is (9)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Common Startup
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Successfully deleted the startup task
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Analyzing the following command line argument:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - /appfabric:C:\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Found the following command line option:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - appfabric
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Found the following custom file location:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - C:\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Analyzing the following command line argument:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - /continue
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Continuing after restart
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Details of the current operating system: 
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Major version number of the operating system:  (10)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (0)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X3839=14393)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X192=402)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_SERVER
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Product type:  (8)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - OS type:  (1)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - PowerShellVersion
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - 5.1.14393.0
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - 4.6.01586
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
2017-07-05 12:02:07 - Reading version of the following file...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - The version is...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 1.0.3010.0
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 11.3.6518.0
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server\CurrentVersion
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 12.2.5543.11
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Windows Server AppFabric
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - ProductVersion
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Microsoft Identity Extensions
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 2.0.1459.0
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client 2.1
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - 1.0.621.117
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.6
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.6
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Cumulative Update Package 7 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB3092423)
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - IsInstalled
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB3092423
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2012
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x64
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2015
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64
2017-07-05 12:02:08 - Beginning download/installation
2017-07-05 12:02:09 - Created thread for installer
2017-07-05 12:02:09 - Installing windows server roles and features.
2017-07-05 12:02:09 - Preparing to run the following commands:
2017-07-05 12:02:09 - Param(
[String]$logFile
)
Import-Module Servermanager
Start-Transcript -path $logFile
$operation = Add-WindowsFeature NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ,NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45,NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,Web-Server,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing,Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-Net-Ext,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,WAS,WAS-Process-Model,WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Xps-Viewer -verbose
 if ($operation.ExitCode -eq 'SuccessRestartRequired') {
 Stop-Transcript
$host.SetShouldExit(3010)
}
elseif (!$operation.Success){
 Stop-Transcript
$host.SetShouldExit(1000)
exit
}
2017-07-05 12:02:10 - Logs for these operations will be available at:
2017-07-05 12:02:10 - "C:\Users\mimadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\PreE4F.tmp.PS1.log"
2017-07-05 12:02:10 - Executing PowerShell command:
2017-07-05 12:02:10 - "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\Users\mimadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\PreE4F.tmp.PS1 -logFile C:\Users\mimadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\PreE4F.tmp.PS1.log"
2017-07-05 12:02:11 - Request for install time of Web Server (IIS) Role
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - Request for install time of Web Server (IIS) Role
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - Install process returned (0)
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - [In HRESULT format] (0)
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - Installing Windows Server AppFabric.
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - DCC
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Features
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - DCS
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Features
2017-07-05 12:02:12 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - DCA
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Features
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - configuring FTP/Windows Services for AppFabric
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - Warning : Call to OpenService(...,SERVICE_START | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE) function to get handle to the service failed (0X424=1060)
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - Warning : [In HRESULT format] (0X80070424=-2147023836)
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - FTP service is not installed.
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - The current status of the service is...
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - SERVICE_RUNNING
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - Windows update service is already running
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - Warning : Call to OpenService(...,SERVICE_START | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE) function to get handle to the service failed (0X424=1060)
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - Warning : [In HRESULT format] (0X80070424=-2147023836)
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - AppFabric caching service is not installed.
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - All services have been configured successfully for AppFabric.
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - Installing Windows Server AppFabric
2017-07-05 12:02:13 - "C:\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe" /i CacheClient,CachingService,CacheAdmin /gac
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - Install process returned (0X643=1603)
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - [In HRESULT format] (0X80070643=-2147023293)
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - All services have been configured successfully after AppFabric installation
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - Last return code (0X643=1603)
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - Flags
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:54 - PendingFileRenameOperations
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Reading the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Error: The tool was unable to install Windows Server AppFabric.
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Last return code (0X643=1603)
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Cannot retry
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - PowerShellVersion
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - 5.1.14393.0
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - The value is... 
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - 4.6.01586
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Reading version of the following file...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - The version is...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - 1.0.3010.0
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Reading the following string value/name...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - Version
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - from the following registry location...
2017-07-05 12:02:55 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
```

I've found the command it runs after a reboot, which is the same command as above to install, but with a /continue switch afterward. So I ran this command also and it continues the reboot chain. 
Any ideas how I can install this irritating software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discovering [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/02/21/sharepoint-2013-prerequisites-fails-with-msi-installer-error-code-1603-while-installing-appfabric-1-1/) I changed the *PSModulePath* in *Environment Variables* to include:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

And it miraculously installed without issue.